# How to switch split screen Emacs where one screen is the editor while the other is terminal emulator? 

Tags: emacs, terminal-emulator

I have ssh'ed to a remote machine and started emacs. I opened one small python application, and then split the screen into two, and M-x terminal-emulator in the other. I would like to edit the script in one section, then press C-x o and run it on the other section. Unfortunately, I can't seem to C-x o away from the terminal emulator and it just ends up typing x o.

Is there a better quick way of doing what I'm trying to do? Or is there a keystroke that will let me switch back to the editor section?

**Edit**: I just tried doing 'M-x shell', instead of 'M-x term', and that allows me to use C-x o to switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While at the * terminal* window, C-^ o to switch to other window, and C-^ C-h for more help.

Comment: For some reason C-^ o isn't working for me.  If anyone else finds the same, I've found switching to char mode with C-c C-k followed by C-c o works (C-c behaves like C-x in char mode of the terminal emulator) - http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html#Term-Mode

Comment: @BryceThomas: Switching to char mode with `C-c C-k` sounds like a feature of one of Emacs' other terminal emulators, `M-x term`, not of `M-x terminal-emulator` — the two are entirely independent, with different features and key bindings.  (FWIW the Emacs 24.4 NEWS file is expected to announce "*terminal.el is obsolete; use term.el instead.*")  [Apols for responding to such an old comment; others in my position might find this useful.]

Answer (score 1):

ALT-X other-window

C-TAB also works locally.  Will that translate over SSH?  If not, bind other-window to another key that will go over SSH.

Comment: Thanks! Also found that 'M-x shell' registers the 'C-x o' keystroke by 'M-x term' does not.

Comment: I voted this up, but my suggestion would be to just use M-x shell instead, unless you really need something in term that you can't get from shell.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post and I customized the .emacs file accordingly.
http://nex-3.com/posts/45-efficient-window-switching-in-emacs